# Mongoose & selecting specific fields during populate in queryOptions?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

While there are a number of answer explaining how to populate specific fields using `.populate`, I am wondering whether the same can be done as part of the `populate` field in the queryOptions?

For example, if my schemas are:

```js
AuthorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
  nationality: String,
  dateOfBirth: Date
});

BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author' }
});
```

And the query would be along the lines of:

```js
  const queryOptions = {
    limit: limit,
    skip: skip,
    populate: [{
      author: { name: 1 }
    }]
  };

  const books = await Book.find(query, null, queryOptions);
```

Can this be achieved this way?

BTW assume Mongoose 5.6.7+.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/stack-overflow", { useNewUrlParser: true })

const AuthorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    nationality: String,
    dateOfBirth: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
const Author = mongoose.model("Author", AuthorSchema)

const BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author' }
});
const Book = mongoose.model("Book", BookSchema)

Book.
find({}).
populate("author",{name: 1}).
skip(0).
limit(1).
exec().
then(books => {
    console.log("books", books)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: I am actually looking for the approach that does not use the `.populate()` function.